# Oracle sql. finding last quarter's last date for given number of dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the last quarter's last date and insert into another column for dates from present in a column. i.e read from the same table and insert into another column

EX

```
column 1 | column 2
02-aug-16|30-jun-16
05-dec-16|30-sep-16
```

Comment: please explain with some sample data

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to insert a value in a column, and also assuming - if your date is not in the correct date datatype but instead is a string, then you know how to change it to a date with `to_date()` ...

the only remaining question is, given a date, how do you find the last date of the previous quarter.

`trunc()` can used with a date parameter. The function truncates the input date. You can give it a second argument to show what to truncate to. 'q' is for quarter. So `trunc(date_col, 'q')` will return the first day of the "current" quarter (current to the value stored in `date_col`, that is). Then you can subtract 1 (which means one day) to get the last day of the previous quarter.

```
SQL> select sysdate as today, trunc(sysdate, 'q') - 1 as last_day_of_prev_qtr from dual;

TODAY      LAST_DAY_OF_PREV_QTR
---------- --------------------
2016-08-02 2016-06-30
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, truncate the source date to a quarter start and substract one day

```
select col1, TRUNC(col1,'Q') - interval '1' day col2 
from (
  select cast('02-aug-16' as date) col1 from dual
  union all 
  select cast('05-dec-16' as date) col1 from dual
);
```

Comment: How is this different from what I posted 10 minutes ago? If it is not different, why is it needed?

Comment: Essentially it uses the same features but applied to the data provided by OP, which may be easier to understand. I don't mind deleting my post if you object it.